# Regex pattern that doesn't accept names starting with spaces in HTML

Tags: html, regex

I have this pattern for names in HTML:

`[a-zA-Z ]{5,}`

It's accepting 5 spaces.

I want a pattern that does not accept names that start with a space.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change

```
[a-zA-Z ]{5,}
```

to

```
[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z ]{4,}
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

```
pattern="^[a-zA-Z]+(\s[a-zA-Z]+)?$"
```

Comment: This appears to only work in cases which have either zero or one spaces, but names can have multiple spaces.